# Solution for losing the embedded message after the Compression

Tags: security, compression, jpeg, steganography

Hello Guys i hope that you are doing great , i have my final project presentation on sunday and am really struggling , The project is about the steganography we are  using jsteg algorithm the teacher asked us to use JPEG compression and to insert the secret message after the quantification matrix  , the steps that am following are :

- DCT , Quantization , inserting the secret message , Inverse of the quantization , IDCT --> getting the stego image
  and in order to extract data am applying on the stego image a 2nd compression:
- DCT , quantization , extracting the secret message
  The problem is the message extracted is wrong , when i did researches i've found that JPEG is a lossy compression which means using the 2nd compression we will lose the hidded message
  It's been more than a month trying to figure it out , but still didn't find any solution
  Do you have any suggestions in mind ?
  Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're misundersanding the Jsteg algorithm. The jpeg encoding process goes 1. split image pixels to 8x8 blocks, 2. dct these blocks, 3. quantise these DCT blocks (**this is lossy**), 4. store these coefficients to a jpeg file using a **lossless** method. Jsteg embeds your secret between steps 3 and 4. To load a jpeg you reverse the steps 4->1. In order to extract the Jsteg secret, you need to reverse step 4 from a jpeg file and then read the secret from the DCT blocks. Basically, you need to replicate a lot of code from a jpeg encoder/decoder.